# How to count specific values of a pandas dataframe column attribute

Tags: python, pandas, csv, count

In my pandas dataframe I have a column named "crashhour" which have two values that is offtime and picktime. How to take only the values of offtime.
Below is the code of Column value count.

```
a=df.crashhour.value_counts()
```

And this is the output-

```
offtime     19639
picktime    14068
Name: crashhour, dtype: int64
```

I want to store only the offtime values in a variable like 19639 should be the output. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
var = a.loc['offtime']
```